# sp_ineachdb and SP_MSFOREACHDB return only 50 records instead of hundreds

Tags: sql, sql-server

When i try to use SP_MSFOREACHDB or sp_ineachdb it returns only 50 (with sp_msforeachdb ) and 48 (with sp_ineachdb ) results, instead of hundreds of results that should b returned. I see the results per DB when execute the code per DB without using the above procedures.
But what can be the issue, i need to run the code for all dbs and not only specific one.
This is the code:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#identity_columns') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #identity_columns
GO

CREATE TABLE #identity_columns
( [database_name] SYSNAME NOT NULL,
[schema_name] SYSNAME NOT NULL,
table_name SYSNAME NOT NULL,
column_name SYSNAME NOT NULL,
[type_name] SYSNAME NOT NULL,
maximum_identity_value BIGINT NOT NULL,
current_identity_value BIGINT NULL,
percent_consumed DECIMAL(25,4) NULL );

DECLARE @Table_Name NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @Schema_Name NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @command varchar(1000);

SELECT @command= '
INSERT INTO #identity_columns
([database_name], [schema_name], table_name, column_name, [type_name], maximum_identity_value, current_identity_value)
SELECT
DB_NAME() AS database_name,
''' + schemas.name + ''' AS schema_name,
''' + tables.name + ''' AS table_name,
''' + columns.name + ''' AS column_name,
''' + types.name + ''' AS type_name,
CASE
WHEN ''' + types.name + ''' = ''TINYINT'' THEN CAST(255 AS BIGINT)
WHEN ''' + types.name + ''' = ''SMALLINT'' THEN CAST(32767 AS BIGINT)
WHEN ''' + types.name + ''' = ''INT'' THEN CAST(2147483647 AS BIGINT)
WHEN ''' + types.name + ''' = ''BIGINT'' THEN CAST(9223372036854775807 AS BIGINT)
WHEN ''' + types.name + ''' IN (''DECIMAL'', ''NUMERIC'') THEN CAST(REPLICATE(9, (' + CAST(columns.precision AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ' - ' + CAST(columns.scale AS VARCHAR(MAX)) + ')) AS BIGINT)
ELSE -1
END AS maximum_identity_value,
IDENT_CURRENT(''[' + schemas.name + '].[' + tables.name + ']'') AS current_identity_value;
'
FROM sys.tables
INNER JOIN sys.columns
ON tables.object_id = columns.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.types
ON types.user_type_id = columns.user_type_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas
ON schemas.schema_id = tables.schema_id
WHERE columns.is_identity = 1;

EXEC dbo.sp_ineachdb @command
UPDATE #identity_columns
SET percent_consumed = CAST(CAST(current_identity_value AS DECIMAL(25,4)) / CAST(maximum_identity_value AS DECIMAL(25,4)) AS DECIMAL(25,2)) * 100;
select * from #identity_columns order by percent_consumed desc
```

expect a lot of records (only for one of these DBs i have more then 300) and returned only 50

Comment: Print out the value of `@command` before you pass it to the stored proc. Realise that you've effectively "hard coded" it to one arbitrary combination of schema/table/column in the current database.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: Sorry i meant sp_msforeachDB and not table

Comment: Sorry, can you please write example, what do you mean Print out the value of @command ?

Comment: I use sql management studio 18

Answer (score 1):

You're only querying the system tables (sys.tables, etc) in the current database. That whole query should be inside the @command.  So simply

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#identity_columns') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #identity_columns
GO

CREATE TABLE #identity_columns
( [database_name] SYSNAME NOT NULL,
[schema_name] SYSNAME NOT NULL,
table_name SYSNAME NOT NULL,
column_name SYSNAME NOT NULL,
[type_name] SYSNAME NOT NULL,
maximum_identity_value BIGINT NOT NULL,
current_identity_value BIGINT NULL,
percent_consumed DECIMAL(25,4) NULL );


declare @sql nvarchar(max) = '
INSERT INTO #identity_columns
([database_name], [schema_name], table_name, column_name, [type_name], maximum_identity_value, current_identity_value)
SELECT
DB_NAME() AS database_name,
schemas.name  AS schema_name,
tables.name  AS table_name,
columns.name  AS column_name,
types.name  AS type_name,
CASE
WHEN types.name  = ''TINYINT'' THEN CAST(255 AS BIGINT)
WHEN types.name  = ''SMALLINT'' THEN CAST(32767 AS BIGINT)
WHEN types.name  = ''INT'' THEN CAST(2147483647 AS BIGINT)
WHEN types.name  = ''BIGINT'' THEN CAST(9223372036854775807 AS BIGINT)
WHEN types.name  IN (''DECIMAL'', ''NUMERIC'') THEN CAST(REPLICATE(9,  columns.precision -  columns.scale )  AS BIGINT)
ELSE -1
END AS maximum_identity_value,
IDENT_CURRENT( concat(quotename(schemas.name),''.'',quotename( tables.name ) ) ) AS current_identity_value
FROM sys.tables
INNER JOIN sys.columns
ON tables.object_id = columns.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.types
ON types.user_type_id = columns.user_type_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas
ON schemas.schema_id = tables.schema_id
WHERE columns.is_identity = 1;
'

print @sql

exec (@sql)

select * from #identity_columns
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Worked with sp_ineachdb (returned actual 1300 results from different dbs), for some reason SP_MSFOREACHDB still returns only 200 but as I understand from google this undocumented proc has a lot of issues.